# How can I ignore a function for coverage?

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, esbuild

handler.ts:

[image: Code with lines.]

Coverage report:

```
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |   97.05 |      100 |      75 |   96.96 |
 src             |   96.87 |      100 |   66.66 |   96.77 |
  handler.ts     |   96.87 |      100 |   66.66 |   96.77 | 90
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  transform: {
    '.(js|ts)$': ['esbuild-jest', { sourcemap: true }],
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
};
```

I bet the transform is the issue, just don't know how to fix it.

Tried:

- adding `/* istanbul ignore next */` on line 88
- adding  `/* istanbul ignore next */`  after the word `export` on line 89
- adding  `/* istanbul ignore next */`  after the word `return` on line 90

When I do I still get an uncovered line. All the middleware etc makes actually testing that function not worth the effort.

Comment: _"I bet the transform is the issue"_ - esbuild only retains [legal comments](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#legal-comments). But if _"All the middleware etc makes actually testing that function not worth the effort"_, which seems fair enough, then _shouldn't_ it show as uncovered? It's _not_ covered.

Comment: I needed the line numbers and I didn't want to take the time to write them in

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, it's not covered but in this case it's not worth testing it so skipping it (and noting why it's being skipped) is a valid use case. Your comment about "legal comments" isn't clarifying things. A single line comment block sure looks "legal" to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a [parsing hint](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#parsing-hints-ignoring-lines) comment *is* the correct way to ignore a function, but esbuild **only** includes ["legal comments"](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#legal-comments) in the build output (emphasis mine):

> A "legal comment" is considered to be any statement-level comment in
> JS or rule-level comment in CSS **that contains `@license` or
> `@preserve` or that starts with `//!` or `/*!`**. These comments are
> preserved in output files by default since that follows the intent of
> the original authors of the code.

So given an actual MRE:

```js
// index.js

export default function foo() {
    console.log("Can't touch this");
}
```

```js
// index.test.js

import func from "./index";

it("doesn't test anything", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "\\.js$": ["esbuild-jest", { sourcemap: true }],
    },
};
```

```js
// package.json

{
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.17.14",
    "esbuild-jest": "^0.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

with the output:

```
$ npm t -- --coverage

> test
> jest --coverage

 PASS  ./index.test.js
  ✓ doesn't test anything (1 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 |
 index.js |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.16 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

you can get to 100% coverage by adding a parsing hint *containing `@preserve`* so that it still appears in the *output* from esbuild:

```js
// index.js

/* istanbul ignore next @preserve */
export default function foo() {
    console.log("Can't touch this");
}
```

New output:

```
$ npm t -- --coverage

> test
> jest --coverage

 PASS  ./index.test.js
  ✓ doesn't test anything (1 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |
 index.js |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.363 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```